# C# 11 raw string literals with ExecuteSqlRawAsync on PostgreSQL have case sensitive problem

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I encountered an issue while attempting to modify my SQL query to address warnings about potential SQL injection. I aimed to parameterize the query and use raw string literals, but I received an error message instead.

It seems the error is related to the case sensitivity of my column names, and unfortunately, I can't alter the entire database to lowercase them.

I've experimented with various other approaches, but they either resulted in errors or failed to correctly retrieve the UserId.

Below is the code I tried.

1. Original Version (SQL injection problem)

```
await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
$@"
    DO $$ 
    BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ""Notification"" WHERE ""UserId"" = '{userId}') > 20 THEN
            DELETE FROM ""Notification""
            WHERE ""UserId"" = '{userId}' AND ""IsReceived"" = 'TRUE' AND ""ContentId"" NOT IN (
                SELECT ""ContentId"" FROM ""Notification""
                WHERE ""UserId"" = '{userId}'
                ORDER BY ""CreatedAt"" DESC
                LIMIT 20
            );
        END IF;
    END $$"
);
```

2. Raw string literals Version

(error: Npgsql.PostgresException : 42703: column "userid" does not exist)

```
var param = new NpgsqlParameter("@UserId", userId);
await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
"""
    DO $$ 
    BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Notification" WHERE "UserId" = @UserId) > 20 THEN
            DELETE FROM "Notification"
            WHERE "UserId" = @UserId AND "IsReceived" = 'TRUE' AND "ContentId" NOT IN (
                SELECT "ContentId" FROM "Notification"
                WHERE "UserId" = @UserId
                ORDER BY "CreatedAt" DESC
                LIMIT 20
            );
        END IF;
    END $$
""", param);
```

3. Raw string literals Version with ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync

(error: Npgsql.PostgresException : 42703: column "p0" does not exist)

```
await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
$"""
    DO $$ 
    BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Notification" WHERE "UserId" = {userId}) > 20 THEN
            DELETE FROM "Notification"
            WHERE "UserId" = {userId} AND "IsReceived" = 'TRUE' AND "ContentId" NOT IN (
                SELECT "ContentId" FROM "Notification"
                WHERE "UserId" = {userId}
                ORDER BY "CreatedAt" DESC
                LIMIT 20
            );
        END IF;
    END $$
""");
```

I'd appreciate guidance on the best way to proceed with modifications.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Your #3 snippet needs quotes around the `{userId}` parameters.  Triple quoting does not alter the case of the string, so there's something else happening in your #2 snippet.

Comment: @TimRoberts _"Your #3 snippet needs quotes around the"_ - no it does not AFAIK. It should behave the same as 2nd one (and it basically does) - EF should create parameterized query from the `FormattableString` accepted by `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync`. Otherwise it would have all the same SQL injections problems as the first one and there would be no point in introduction of such method.

Comment: @GuruStron  No.  He's not using Postgres substitution.  Notice he's not passing parameters.  He's using C# $ string substitution, so it will still have injection problems.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes there is substitution, no there is no injection problems if method is correctly used. That is the goal of [`RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolatedasync?view=efcore-7.0) - _"Any parameter values you supply will automatically be converted to a DbParameter."_

Comment: @TimRoberts see that it accepts `FormattableString`, not just `string`. Compiler will not build the `string` and this allows EF to see all the `{}` placeholders and their values and turn them into query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF` isn't actually necessary, so you could just use a normal `SqlInterpolated` block (ie fully parameterized).

```cs
await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
$"""
    DELETE FROM "Notification"
    WHERE "UserId" = {userId}
      AND "IsReceived" = TRUE
      AND "ContentId" NOT IN (
          SELECT n2."ContentId"
          FROM "Notification" n2
          WHERE n2."UserId" = {userId}
          ORDER BY n2."CreatedAt" DESC
          LIMIT 20
      );
""");
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't use parameters with `DO`. From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html):

> `DO` executes an anonymous code block, or in other words a transient anonymous function in a procedural language.
> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void. It is parsed and executed a single time.

So it treats the parameter names as column names (and obviously fails).

So just rewrite the query so no `DO` is needed or create a database function and use EF to invoke it with parameters.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530673/2501279).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It turns out I misunderstood the functionality of the DO statement.